# check if device online via ping ip when ip changes

Tags: linux, networking, ping, arp, nmap

Suppose I have the following situation. I have a Linux box sitting inside a local network, and that box will periodically ping the ip addresses of other devices on the network to make sure they are up. Also assume I know the MAC addresses of these devices, which I obtained via ARP at some point in the past. Now assume that one of the devices goes down and when it comes back up it is assigned a new ip address. How can I modify my periodic ping check to ping the new ip address? Yes I know I can check the arp table on my Linux box to get the new ip address if the record exists. But what guarantee do I have that the arp able on that box has been updated properly? Is there any way to quckly force the arp table on my Linux box to update and somehow find the new ip address for the known mac address?

Comment: You can update ARP table with unicasts. See http://superuser.com/questions/29640/inverse-arp-lookup

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts would be to disable DHCP and set these addresses statically unless it is critical that they cycle through different addresses.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This is not helpful. I have no control over DHCP in this environment. I'm looking for an answer that specifically addresses the question.